# Mongoose NodeJs: erro ao se conectar com o MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando fazer conexão com o banco de dados MongoDB mas ocorre o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando eu rodo o comando do servidor mongod:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguem me ajudar a encontrar a solução, ficarei agradecido

Comment: Coloque seu código como texto e não como imagem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua aplicação, mude a porta. 
O erro EADDRINUSE quer dizer que sua porta 8081 já está em uso por alguma outra aplicação.

Comment: tenho que colocar a mesma porta que o servidor mongodb está usando? ou qualquer outra?

Comment: Não. você tem que usar qualquer outra porta que esteja livre na sua máquina. Ex: 8080, 3000, 5000 .. e por ai vai.

Comment: mudei aqui a porta e deu certo, Muito obrigado =D